# Using async functions in a web worker results in typeError

Tags: webpack

I am using react/webpack (version 5) and trying to develop a web worker. Based on this https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/ I created a very simple worker. Here is the code:

```
async function waitFor(duration) {

}

self.onmessage = ({ data: { fileSpec } }) => {
  console.log('Would doing a file transfer for filename: ' + fileSpec.name);

  self.postMessage({
    answer: 42,
  });
};
```

Using this code in my main thread I get a TypeError with chrome showing that execOptions.factory is undefined (in function **webpack_require**(moduleId) )

```
    this.transferWorker = new Worker(new URL('common/fileTransfer/transferWorker.js', import.meta.url));
    this.transferWorker.postMessage({fileSpec: this.dataTransferCtrl.fileSpec});
    this.transferWorker.onmessage = ({ data: { answer } }) => {
      console.log(answer);
    };
```

If I remove the async keyword from the function definition then all is fine. Are async/await supported for webworker with webpack?

Comment: The `async` function you're thinking is the problem — why is it empty, and why don't we see it referenced in your code?

Comment: It is because I peeled off things one by one until it started working as expected. In the end, I had that empty function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turned out that all is working properly, including with the async keyword. I simply had to repackage everything with webpack by killing the running development browser and doing a fresh start using npm start
I guess the hot replacement module magic is good but sometime it can not make miracles....